# How can I defer handling a push notification in a running ios app?

Tags: ios, push-notification

If `application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` is triggered in my running app, but I don't want to handle it right now, is it possible to leave it posted in the Notification Center so the user can swipe down later and click on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, active apps get the push notification directly and the notification will not be added to the notification center.

You will have to handle it directly or store it your self for later use.